# How to normalize data in a text file while preserving the first variable

Tags: python

I have a text file with this format:

```
1   10.0e+08   1.0e+04   1.0
2    9.0e+07   9.0e+03   0.9
2    8.0e+07   8.0e+03   0.8
3    7.0e+07   7.0e+03   0.7
```

I would like to preserve the first variable of every line and to then normalize the data for all lines by the data on the first line. The end result would look something like;

```
1   1.0   1.0   1.0
2   0.9   0.9   0.9
2   0.8   0.8   0.8
3   0.7   0.7   0.7
```

so essentially, we are doing the following:

```
1   10.0e+08/10.0e+08   1.0e+04/1.0e+04   1.0/1.0
2    9.0e+07/10.0e+08   9.0e+03/1.0e+04   0.9/1.0
2    8.0e+07/10.0e+08   8.0e+03/1.0e+04   0.8/1.0
3    7.0e+07/10.0e+08   7.0e+03/1.0e+04   0.7/1.0
```

I'm still researching and reading on how to do this. I'll upload my attempt shortly. Also can anyone point me to a place where I can learn more about manipulating data files?

Comment: how big is your file?

Comment: A few thousand lines

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your file into a numpy array and use numpy broadcast feature:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('foo.txt')
data = data / data[0]
#array([[ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ],
#       [ 2.  ,  0.09,  0.9 ,  0.9 ],
#       [ 2.  ,  0.08,  0.8 ,  0.8 ],
#       [ 3.  ,  0.07,  0.7 ,  0.7 ]])
np.savetxt('new.txt', data)
```

Comment: I added a line to the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to write this data out in the same format that the data was read in? (without comma's and square brackets). Also, when I run this for data with more lines it seems to hide/delete data in the middle. I see the first 6 lines followed by ,,,. and then the last 6 lines. Where's all the data?

Comment: Numpy does not display the whole array, unless you ask it.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick..... awesome! I really appreciate the help! Any suggestions where I can start learning or material that will help a beginner such as myself?

Comment: May I shamelessly direct you to my book.  https://pragprog.com/book/dzpyds/data-science-essentials-in-python

Comment: I didn't know I was being helped by someone with your stature! I'll will definitely be ordering your book. Thanks again for taking the time to help!

Comment: Dmitry, it seems that when I run this for a file with 3,000 lines it stops normalizing the data on line 1,357 and on, displaying the "un-normalized" data . Any suggestions why this might be happening?

Comment: It would help if you show the data on line 1356 and 1357.

Comment: Here is some data for lines 1, 500, 1000, 1356 and 1357. As you will notice there is a change in power from lines 1356 to 1357 and this continues after line 1357.                                                                       line 1:        1.000e+00 1.00e+00 1.00e+00 1.00e+00 1.00e+00 1.00e+00 line 500:    5.000e+02 3.50e-03  3.00e-03  5.00e-03  4.00e-03  1.25e-03 line 1000:  1.000e+03 1.75e-04  1.75e-04  3.25e-04  2.00e-04  6.75e-05 line 1356:  1.356e+03 4.00e-04  4.00e-04  3.00e-04  2.25e-04  5.50e-05
line 1357:  1.357e+03 1.50e+05 4.50e-02  1.25e+00 7.50e-01  5.00e-01

Comment: FYI, Each number runs to 18 decimal places when it saves out. The original data only shows 7 decimal places. Could this be related to memory? Is there a way to have the code write out the number to 7 decimal places? Maybe that would have an effect.

Comment: Also, I ran a test where I removed the first 500 lines and noticed the same outcome. The data stops being normalized after approximately 1356 lines.

Comment: I went ahead and changed your code from: data /= data[0]    to    data = data/data[0] . That seems to have done the trick. Any ideas on what was going on?

Comment: Oh.... I see where the problem is. It is actually quite subtle, and you are right, your method is preferred.